# MapReduce 2 without YARN

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

Considering the fact that YARN is a better option to run mapreduce2, but is it possible to run MR2 without YARN?
I tried using MR2 but it runs with YARN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MRv2 is actually YARN! So, no you can't run mapreduce2 jobs without YARN!

[Official documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YARN.html) :

> Apache Hadoop NextGen MapReduce (YARN)
>
> MapReduce has undergone a complete overhaul in hadoop-0.23 and we now
>   have, what we call, MapReduce 2.0 (MRv2) or YARN.
>
> The fundamental idea of MRv2 is to split up the two major
>   functionalities of the JobTracker, resource management and job
>   scheduling/monitoring, into separate daemons. The idea is to have a
>   global ResourceManager (RM) and per-application ApplicationMaster
>   (AM). An application is either a single job in the classical sense of
>   Map-Reduce jobs or a DAG of jobs.